# Variational AutoEncoder fails with generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to train a variational autoencoder on a set of images from the celeba dataset.
I have attached the code and the error that it gives below.

The idea of this model is to give an input the image and get as an output through the decoder an image as well . I want the generator to give only the image with no labels.

the same model was tried with the MNIST dataset and worked considered as (150,150,1) (model was built to handle one channel) with model.fit where the dataset was loaded before and y=None

images here are RGB (3 channels) and keras version is 2.0.8

```
import keras
from keras import layers
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img_shape=(150,150,3)
batch_size = 16
latent_dim = 2


input_img = keras.Input(shape=img_shape)

x = layers.Conv2D ( 32,3,
                 padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(input_img)

x = layers.Conv2D ( 64 ,3,
                  padding = 'same', activation = 'relu',
                  strides = (2,2))(x)

x = layers.Conv2D ( 64,3,
                 padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(x)

x = layers.Conv2D ( 64,3,
                  padding='same', activation = 'relu')(x)

shape_before_flattening = K.int_shape(x)

x = layers.Flatten()(x)

x = layers.Dense(32,activation='relu')(x)

z_mean=layers.Dense (latent_dim)(x)
z_log_var=layers.Dense (latent_dim)(x)


def sampling(args):
    z_mean,z_log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim),
                             mean=0. , stddev=1.)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var) * epsilon
z = layers.Lambda(sampling)([z_mean,z_log_var])


decoder_input = layers.Input(K.int_shape(z)[1:])

x = layers.Dense ( np.prod ( shape_before_flattening[1:]),
                 activation = 'relu')(decoder_input)

x = layers.Reshape(shape_before_flattening[1:])(x)

x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32,3,
                        padding='same',
                        activation='relu',
                        strides=(2,2))(x)

x = layers.Conv2D (3, 3, 
                  padding = 'same',
                  activation = 'sigmoid')(x)

decoder = Model(decoder_input,x)

z_decoded = decoder (z)


class CustomVariationalLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def vae_loss(self, x,z_decoded):
        
        x = K.flatten(x)
        
        z_decoded = K.flatten(z_decoded)
        
        xent_loss = keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(x,z_decoded)
        
        kl_loss = -5e-4 * K.mean(
                1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis = -1)
        return K.mean(xent_loss + kl_loss)
    
    def call(self,inputs):
        x = inputs [0]
        
        z_decoded = inputs[1]
        
        loss = self.vae_loss(x,z_decoded)
        
        self.add_loss(loss,inputs=inputs)
        
        return x
    
y = CustomVariationalLayer()([input_img,z_decoded])


vae = Model (input_img,y)

vae.compile (optimizer = 'rmsprop' , loss = None )

vae.summary()
```

Here is the model summary

```
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 150, 150, 3)   0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 150, 150, 32)  896         input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 75, 75, 64)    18496       conv2d_1[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)                (None, 75, 75, 64)    36928       conv2d_2[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)                (None, 75, 75, 64)    36928       conv2d_3[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 360000)        0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 32)            11520032    flatten_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 2)             66          dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                  (None, 2)             66          dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)                (None, 2)             0           dense_2[0][0]                    
                                                                   dense_3[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_3 (Model)                  (None, 150, 150, 3)   1099331     lambda_2[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
custom_variational_layer_2 (Cust [(None, 150, 150, 3), 0           input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                   model_3[1][0]                    
====================================================================================================
Total params: 12,712,743
Trainable params: 12,712,743
Non-trainable params: 0
```

then the code left

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# All images will be rescaled by 1./255
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
# datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        base_dir,
        target_size=(150,150),
        batch_size= batch_size,
        classes=['train'],
        class_mode=None)

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        base_dir,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        classes=['validation'],
        class_mode=None)

history = vae.fit_generator(train_generator,
       epochs = 1,
        steps_per_epoch =10)
```

and the error is as following  when I run fit_generator

```
Epoch 1/1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-f56d54f45804> in <module>()
      1 history = vae.fit_generator(train_generator,
      2        epochs = 1,
----> 3         steps_per_epoch =10)
      4 #        validation_data = (validation_generator, None),
      5 #                  validation_steps=10)

...\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     85                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     86                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 87             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     88         wrapper._original_function = func
     89         return wrapper

...\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2025                                          'a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` '
   2026                                          'or `(x, y)`. Found: ' +
-> 2027                                          str(generator_output))
   2028                     # build batch logs
   2029                     batch_logs = {}

ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: [[[[0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   ...
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00784314]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]]

  [[0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   ...
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00784314]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]]

  [[0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   ...
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00784314]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]
   [0.03921569 0.01960784 0.00392157]]

  ...
```

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: Edited code to show where error happens.
It is when I run the fit_generator